# How can I print in multicolor with Ender 6?

Tags: marlin, firmware, creality-ender-6

I'd like to make multicolor printing on Ender 6, but it seems that the filament change (`ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE`) doesn't work (it works on my Ender 3).
Can you help me how can I solve that? How can I make the `ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE` available on Ender 6?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling `ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE` requires a rebuild and upload/install of a new Marlin firmware. The option is found in the advanced configuration file ([Configuration_adv.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h)).

Please change:

```
//#define ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE
```

to:

```
#define ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE
```

Rebuild and install the firmware.